# How to use Web3Js to sign a message in a react native mobile app

Tags: web3js, react, mobile-wallet, ios

I am very new to Ethereum. I have requirement to sign the app using Web3JS in my React native mobile App.

I used [this link](https://medium.com/@dxenu/react-native-0-60-4-with-web3-js-1-2-0-8090a1decee2) to get web3js working properly.
But I am not sure how to connect to wallet in mobile app. Please guide. Thanks.